# Freemarker Eclipse Plug-In

Tags: eclipse, freemarker

How can I install Freemarker Plug-In in eclipse?

I googled it and found this site

https://sites.google.com/site/hcao2008site/development/leareclipse/install-freemarker-plugin-in-eclipse

but it did not work for me. The URL "http://www.freemarker.org/eclipse/update" as it has  mentioned in #3 does not exist. Then I tried the URL "http://www.freemarker.org/eclipse/" then it worked but after installation, I added *.ftl as file types inside 
Windows -> Preference -> General -> Editors -> FIle Associations but I could not find the Freemarker editor inside "Associated editors".

I am using Eclipse of Version: Indigo Service Release 1 in windows 7.

Any suggestions please???

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I have installed the freemarker just now, here is the screenshot for it, you can just check it
[image]

Comment: The FreeMarker IDE is part of the JBoss Tools, here is the current update site for Eclipse 4.3 / Kepler IDE: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/kepler/

Comment: Using this plugin in Spring Tool Suite does nothing - no visualization help, just plain text.

Answer (score 35):

You could try the **JBoss Tools** plugins available from http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/development/indigo/, they contain the "FreeMarker IDE" which provides a nice freemarker editor.

I didn't find a screenshot of the editor right now, so I will show you how it looks like in my installation (Indigo on Ubuntu 11.10), so that you can decide if this is what you want:

[image: JBoss Tools' FreeMarker IDE Editor]

Comment: I had to use the following URL: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/JBossTools-3.3.0.Final.core/

Comment: Or through the Eclipse Marketplace, you will find FreeMarker IDE in the JBoss Tools

Comment: I am Eclipse guy but I am considering buying IntelliJ IDEA because  JBoss Tools's Freemarker editor for Eclipse is just a toy. No templates, code completition for imported files, block selection, auto-formating and/or completition for html, completition/help for internal/external macros params, (un)commenting... just basic completition for built-ins and internal macros...

Answer (score 2):

You can install it, from an update site - http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/helios/

For installing, open eclipse, than go to Help > Install New Software >> add the above update site url, From the many installations available from that update site, you can just install the editor, you can just install the ‘FreeMarker IDE’ from All JBoss Tools menu. See below screenshot for help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Jeewan@Feb 21 '12 at 21:38, you are missing the “freemarker” suffix in your link. The complete url is http://www.freemarker.org/eclipse/freemarker/ . It works for me on Eclipse Juno, OS Linux Ubuntu 12.04. @Jason@Sep 28 '12 at 6:59, I don’t understand your answer to mention the solution make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

I found detailed instructions under http://freemarker.org/editors.html in the first table row ("Eclipse", "Part of the JBoss Tools Project. Install like this"). Although I restarted Eclipse as recommended, it was also necessary to reopen each file for the syntax coloring to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

Since July 2016 also published on Eclipse marketplace as separate entry

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/freemarker-ide-jboss-tools

Quote

> This is quick way to install FreeMarker IDE plugin from JBoss Tools
>   http://tools.jboss.org/.
>
> Sources are at https://github.com/jbosstools/jbosstools-freemarker
>   Issue tracker is JBoss Tools JIRA
>   https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE (specify component freemarker)
>
> As recommended on http://freemarker.org/editors.html nightly version
>   is used for Neon.

Answer (score 1):

For **Eclipse Oxygen / Photon**:

The Freemarker Plugin from JBoss Tools was deprecated in the new release for Oxygen, see changelog for JBoss Tools 4.5.0:
https://tools.jboss.org/documentation/whatsnew/jbosstools/4.5.0.AM2.html#freemarker

So I use JBoss Tools 4.4.4 instead (which was for Neon, but seems to work fine with Oxygen):
https://tools.jboss.org/downloads/jbosstools/neon/4.4.4.Final.html#update_site

Installation:
Help > Install New Software > Add `http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/neon/stable/updates/` > Expand `JBoss Application Development` > `Freemarker IDE`